# jQuery smooth scroll anchor links with fixed header and WP admin bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using some JavaScript to create a smooth scroll effect to achnor links. The site has a fixed header so the content needs to be offset by whatever the height of the header is (this varies due to @media rules). On top of this when the user is logged in to WordPress the content needs to be offset further by the height of the WP admin bar (again, the height of this vaires depending on screen size).

I have set up two variables in my script to separately get the height of both these elements:

```js
var headerHeight = $('header').height();
var adminbarHeight = $('#wpadminbar').height();
```

Further on in the script I want to offset the top by the height of the header *plus* the height of the admin bar *if* it exists (i.e. if a user is logged in).

```js
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top - headerHeight - adminbarHeight }, 500,
```

I am trying to offset by the headerHeight and the adminbarHeight but this is not working for me. If I remove 'adminbarHeight' it works but then it does not look correct for logged in users.

Is there something wrong with my syntax? Or perhaps I need to create an if statement to check if the adminbarHeight is greater than 0?

The full script I am enqueueing in my WP child theme is below:

```js
( function( $ ) {
'use strict';

$('a[href*="#"]')
    .not('[href="#"]')
    .not('[href="#0"]')
    .click(function(event) {
        var headerHeight = $('header').height();
        var adminbarHeight = $('#wpadminbar').height();
            if (
            location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
            && 
            location.hostname == this.hostname
            ) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top - headerHeight - adminbarHeight }, 500, 
                    function() {
                    var $target = $(target);
                        $target.focus();
                if ($target.is(":focus")) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $target.attr('tabindex','-1');
                    $target.focus();
                };
            });
        }
    }
});

}( jQuery ) );
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! I am new to JavaScript so apologies if this is a really obvious error.

Thanks,
Chris